# Map attributes as key : value and remove root id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a collection which looks like this when I do render json:

```
0:
   0:
      key: "A"
      random: 1
   1: 
      key: "B"
      random: 3
   2: 
      key: "Z"
      random: 25
   3: 
      etc.
```

Value of key is always different and doesn't duplicate.

What I want is to get values of those two attributes as key : value and remove root id, so instead of separate objects I would like to get array with all key : value pairs.

It should look like this:

```
0:
   "A" : 1
   "B" : 3
   "Z" : 25
```

How can I achieve that in ruby on rails?

EDIT:
Controller code:

```
def index
  @data = RandomKey.select(:key, :random)
  render json: @data
end
```

Comment: that's a pretty print, how does it look raw?

Comment: If you want to ask Ruby questions, don't ask in JSON, ask in Ruby.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to Ruby. How can I print raw object from controller in rails?

Comment: I really don't know how to print it not using json ;/ but it's basically an array of objects of the same type (custom model) and each object has parameters key and random with values.

Comment: how did you do this and what you meant by `when I do render json`? from where do you get that json? share controller/relevant code from where you get that.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to hash using `to_h`

```
@data = RandomKey.pluck(:key, :random).to_h
render json: @data
```

Comment: for rails 5+ only. ;)

Comment: ruby 2.1 onward

Comment: ohh yes, my bad (y)

Comment: It does the job, but is it possible with select instead of pluck?

Comment: @Andrea hwo does it make the difference? `select` vs `pluck`?

Comment: pluck will fire select query only.. just the difference is it will return you array of arrays instead of `ActiveRecord` relation...

Comment: If you want to use select you will have to again convert it to array manually or use another way to convert it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def index
  @data = RandomKey.select(:key, :random).map { |r| [r.key, r.random] }.to_h
  render json: @data
end
```

Comment: It does key : value part, but it's still array of objects (each object has key : random) and not just simple array :/

Comment: check updated answer. To be honest, it doesn't make any difference using `pluck` or `select` in your case atleast.